# Upgrading Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 inside a VMware guest

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, windows-10-upgrade

Now I know one can tell Windows to check for the upgrade eligibility and all. That's *not* my problem.

Yet, I'd like to move to Windows 10 with a (VMware 10 virtual hardware level) guest (running on the latest VMware Workstation 11) that currently runs Windows 8.1.

Alas, when I try that I get to see this:

[image: Windows 10 upgrade not possible due to VMware SVGA 3D]

Now I know for a fact that Windows 10 can run successfully at this compatibility level (i.e. `virtualHW.version = "10"` in the `.vmx` file). I have installed Windows 10 at this virtual hardware level and it runs fine and there is no problem installing VMware Tools, either.

Is there a way to convince the "Get Windows 10" functionality on the client side to do the upgrade irrespective of its alleged compatibility findings? I.e. do it at my own risk?!

Comment: I assume that that is the display adapter. You could try switching the client to using the basic Microsoft driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also try the ISO tool; I haven't had any issues using it... except when not logged on as an administrator account:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10

Good luck

Comment: I want to upgrade and keep using Windows. This is not even purely an academic exercise, because I also need to see how a particular software that I maintain will behave during the upgrade.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - Except you can still do that with the .ISO  The process is exactly the same, minus this compatibility test.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - Have you upgraded hardware both ways?  I actually have.  *I am telling you the process is identical.*  If you choose to ignore a possible solution to your problem that is your choice.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - No;  You don't have to boot to the .ISO in order to use it.  There are existing questions that go into more detail about the .ISO.

Comment: @Ramhound: thanks, then I'll give that a try. Already have those from MSDN.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - Now that think about it.  I am not 100% if the "upgrade now" option will be offered if you simply use the .ISO.  What I said was identical, was the Media Creation Tool, that method has an "upgrade now" option which is identical to the automated Windows Update method.  All you have to do is run the setup, if prompted for a key skip that step, and choose keep everything.

Comment: @Ramhound: so far appears to work. Still not finished. I used an MSDN `.iso` not the Media Creation Tool. The full-screen wizard before the first restart can be dismissed by means of `Win+D` to bring the desktop to the foreground, so any work can be continued during that time. However, the reboot is sudden, so I don't recommend to actually continue working.

Comment: The reboot using the Windows Update method is also sudden.

Comment: @Ramhound: it worked. So it appears you were right. I made screenshots during all phases, and my colleague confirmed that this was essentially the same process.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was put the win 8 VMware in 1024x768 screen and do update to win 10 by dvd. I never got the svga error again. After updating, I removed the vmware tools. Reboot. Go back in new VMware win 10 and install VMware tools to fix the screen resolutions choices, and it functions just fine. Win 10 is in 1440 x 900 and looks great. And goes to 1920x1028 if need be.